# Writing uchar* data to file

Tags: c++

I am using the OpenCV library, which has a class called `Mat`, representing a matrix, with data stored in an array at `uchar* Mat::data`. I want to write this data to a binary file using C++.

Here is my code:

```
cv::Mat m(3, 3, CV_8UC1); // This basically creates a 3-by-3 matrix
std::fstream fileOut("file.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
fileOut.write((char*)m.data, 9); // This should write 9 bytes of data
```

And I am getting the error message:

```
invalid conversion from ‘uchar* {aka unsigned char*}’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’
```

What should I do differently?

Comment: Why not using - OpenCV provided `FileStorage` class for persistence -  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html ?

Comment: which compiler ? for me that code is good on VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

it's an illegal conversion in C++

use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m.data)`